# eclipse doesn't create a XML file for android projects

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, adt

Good Afternoon Stack,

So recently I bought the BigNerdRanch book on android development and after downloading the ADT (Android Development Tools) which included eclipse and SDK manager. I created a new Android Application project and followed the necessary steps to initialize the project but when I opened the project the workbench was clear and I could not find an XML file that the project was supposed to create by default. If anyone is familiar with the text it says that an XML file dubbed 'activity_quiz.xml' should be created and opened by default. It would be in the layout directory of the project, but on my machine nothing has been created.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Any layout should be in /res/layout

Comment: Try this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html Maybe there the steps are explained better than in your nerd book

Comment: You are looking in res\layout .. and you did name your Activity Quiz, right?

Answer (score 0):

its sounds like what you are looking for is activity_main.xml (unless you changed the default name when setting up the application) if this is a brand new android project created from scratch and not imported. if your not exactly sure of where a file is you can search the project with ctrl + shift, r and type in the name wild card search works too so you can type in *activity and it will find all results

Comment: It does not create a activity_main.xml file. I searched using your ctrl+SHIFT+r method and searched *.xml for all the xml files in my project and there were no activity_*.xml files

Comment: @user3261832 when going through the steps did you have "Create Activity" selected its on the 4th screen of the set up

Comment: @user3261832 let me know if an image is needed for the screen i am referring to